# Database redesign using sqlite3

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, database-design

I am afraid that this question might be a little too broad, but I have little-to-none knowledge when it comes to database design, so I will explain what I have so far before I get to the question.

I have an excel file, which I exported into a csv file, which has the following (simplified) layout:

```
Region, License Number in 1st Year, License Number in 2nd Year, License Number in 3rd Year...
```

The idea is that the licenses are incremented and at the end of every year, I have a record of what is the highest license at the time for each region. Because there are almost as many regions as there are years, it makes sense the previous layout for an excel file because we have the data displayed in what is close to be a square, but for the database I believe that it could be easier to deal with it if I reduce the number of columns and I would have this:

```
Region, Year, License Number
```

Assuming that this is right (again, I am clueless when it comes to database design) my question is the following: how can I possibly convert all the data to the suggested format without having to manually create the (many) entries for each region and copy all the licenses into the corresponding years?

The goal is to be able to tell what year a license was issued by simply looking at the license number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're on the right track. You'll want a primary key on {region, year}.

If you're relatively new to databases, the procedure below will be the easiest both for you to understand *and* for you to get right the first try.

One problem is that you don't appear to be storing the years. If *1st year* means the same year for every value in that Excel column--that is, *1st year* doesn't mean 2011 for one row, and 1999 for another--then you might be able to massage the data into shape easily just using a second worksheet.

- Copy the two columns "Regions" and "License number in 1st year" to
  another worksheet.
- If *1st year* means, say, 2005, then insert a column between those
  two, copy the number 2005 all the way down the second column, and
  you're done. (Done with 1st year, that is.)
- Repeat for each year.
- Export the results, and import them into your table.

If you think you're comfortable running queries, you can try this procedure.

- Create a table for your data. I'm guessing at the data types.

  create table your_table_name (
    region varchar(35) not null,
    year integer not null check (year >= 1955),
    license_num integer not null check (license_num >= 0)
  );
- Export your spreadsheet to CSV file. Consider changing the column
  names to the actual years.
- Import into sqlite.

Insert data into your_table_name.

```
insert into your_table_name (region, year, license_num)
select region_column_name, 1955, license_num_column_for_1955
from imported_table_name
```

Note carefully that you'll need to adjust the literal year and the name of the column for that year each time you run the query.

Comment: all the years match up as you said, and that was what first came to my mind, but after I was done with the first 2 years I realized that this is the brute-force approach, and I was looking for something more 'elegant', since doing that for all the years from 1955 to 2005 seems like it's too much... I was trying to avoid making a small program just to parse the data but it looks like I will end up writing for loops inside for loops this time

Comment: One-time project, or recurring?

Comment: also, apparently sqlite3 doesn't let me use a number as a column name, although it is not a huge problem

Comment: your edited answer solved the problem for me, I made a one line script to spit out the sql statement for each year (simple loop from 1995 to 2005) and piped that to the sqlite cli, which took me seconds. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

well.. i'm not real clear on License Number - i think you mean a total (int) count of the number of licenses for the region in that year.

you probably have more info about each region as well.

i assume also that you do not have each individual license, but instead you are just maintaining the count. (if you want to store each license then this answer would be different)

so you will need a region table - something like:

```
region
-------
region_id
name
other_info_possibly
```

then either a license table to store each license - like this

```
license
---------
license_id
region_id
license_issue_date
license_value
other_info_possibly
```

or a summary maybe like this:

```
license_summary
----------------
region_id
license_count
year
```

next, you need to decide where and when to manipulate your original data: before or after importing to the database.

it might be easier after...  in this case, you need a place to dump it in 'raw' maybe :

```
raw_data
---------
region
year1_count
year2_count
-- etc
```

then you can write inserts from this raw_data table to populate the other tables.

Comment: the license is actually like an id that is auto incremented with each new license (every 'person' has his own license), not just a number to count, but your answer applies anyway; however, I would still get stuck when dumping the original data to the 'raw' table, since I would have to do that for every single region (more than 50 times)

Comment: essentially, you will manipulate the csv file into sql statements.  add in the INSERT INTO in the front, then the VALUES and commas etc until you get a working sql statement for each row.  then run the script. (notepad++ might be a good editor for this)

Comment: so you are saying that I can write INSERT INTO within the csv file and that will be processed by the import statement?